How to create a button array from an actor array on Unreal Blueprint?

I have an array of actors named "AcadamyFloor1ButtonActors". Each actor has a widget with a button. I want to extract that button and add it to another array named "AcadamyFloor1ButtonArray". Each widget inside the actor has different names. Meaning no widget has same name. And no Button has same same. How can i do this

i find a way to create a button array from an actor array on Unreal Blueprint 
